# Is "60 frames skipped" something important?

Tags: android

I have a listView with about 60 elements, and this "frames skipped" message usually appears. I'm using an emulator with API 19, and, despite the message, it seems not to be a problem, since the application runs well. Will it be a problem when dealing with other API's?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that this is a problem with emulator (it usually runs slower than physical device)

BUT it may indicate problem with your adapter. 
It would be good if you can paste the code so we can see if you're reusing views, using viewholder patterns and not doing any heavy computation in getView :)

edit: ok, so from the code i can tell you, that you're not reusing convertView in adapter, and you do not use ViewHolder pattern which will bite you later when you develop :)

https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

here you have a link that explains those things more and in depth that i will not achieve in a SO post :)

Comment: 1+ for the explanation.